# Additional parameter in custom sort function in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I was looking at some custom sort function in Javascript & am trying to understand how it really works. Below is the code;

```
sortArrayBy: function(a, b, param) {
   if (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey]) {
        return isAscending ? -1 : 1;
    }
    if (a[sortKey] > b[sortKey]) {
        return isAscending ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return 0;
}

var self = this;
var sortFunc = function(a, b) {
    return self.sortArrayBy(a, b, self.get('sortKey'));  // What is the last param used for here ?
};
myArr.sort(sortFunc, key); // What is 'key' used for here ?
```

My question is in 'sortFunc' defintion, what is the last parameter self.get('sortKey') used for & What is 'key' used for in myArr.sort(sortFunc, key)?

Comment: Where did you find this? Unless `Array#sort()` was redefined, the second parameter `key` that gets passed after `sortFunc` would normally be discarded by the native implementation.

Comment: Even I was thinking the same, but had found this code in one of our projects

Comment: Try to find anywhere that redefines a sort method. If you can, search your project source with the regular expression `sort\w*=`. If that doesn't show up anywhere, there's something really weird going on.

Comment: Can you share the original link where this custom sort function was posted.

Comment: Looks like you are able to set a `sortKey` per object that would used in `sortArrayBy` which would determine the type of sort logic to apply. What did you replace with `// ... sort logic`?

Comment: I have updated the sort logic which I have used